# How can I compress a list with zlib in Erlang and decompress it back?

Tags: erlang, zlib, compression

Let's say I would like to compress the following list and keep the compressed version in RAM:

```
List = lists:seq(1,100000).
```

The example provided in the official [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/zlib.html) doesn't work for me - I get the error for unbound variable `Read` and I do not understand what it is used for (is it a function or a variable?).

I have tried to search on the web, but the only thing that I have found is related to decompressing [files](http://www.trapexit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=51218).

So, the question is: How can I compress the list `List` and decompress it back with the help of `zlib` in Erlang? How can I see what amount of memory is consumed by the `List` and its compressed counterpart?

Comment: `Read` is a fun that returns continuous data (as `iodata()`) or `end_of_data` when there is no more data. You're supposed to implement that yourself (since it is dependent on your application).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compress the data in the following manner:

```
Z=zlib:open(),
zlib:deflateInit(Z),
CData=zlib:deflate(Z2, lists:seq(1,100), finish),
zlib:deflateEnd(Z).
```

To decompress the data you can do:

```
Z=zlib:open(),
zlib:inflateInit(Z),
Data=zlib:Inflate(Z, CData),
zlib:inflateEnd(Z).
```

You can just figure out the size by checking CData.

Answer (score 9):

The [term_to_binary/2](http://erldocs.com/R15B/erts/erlang.html#term_to_binary/2) BIF supports zlib compression:

```
Eshell V5.8.4  (abort with ^G)
1> L = lists:seq(1,100000).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
 23,24,25,26,27,28,29|...]
2> B1 = term_to_binary(L).
<<131,108,0,1,134,160,97,1,97,2,97,3,97,4,97,5,97,6,97,7,
  97,8,97,9,97,10,97,11,97,...>>
3> size(B1).
499242
4> B2 = term_to_binary(L,[compressed]).
<<131,80,0,7,158,41,120,156,20,212,103,27,134,1,192,8,84,
  239,189,247,222,235,81,68,73,200,46,35,84,...>>
5> size(B2).
212752
```

[binary_to_term/1](http://erldocs.com/R15B/erts/erlang.html#binary_to_term/1) will recognize the zlib header and do the right thing.

Comment: isnt term_to_binary EFT format?

Comment: "External Term Format"*